# How to find the range of the function $\frac{e^x log_{e} x 5^{x^2+2} (x^2-7x+10)}{2x^2-11x+12}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

How to find  the range of the function $$\frac{e^x log_{e} x 5^{x^2+2} (x^2-7x+10)}{2x^2-11x+12}$$

We can see the domain of the function is $(\frac{3}{2}, 4) \cup (4, \infty)$ as the denominator is not defined on $\frac{3}{2} \&  4$ and $logx$ is  defined on $x >0$

Please suggest how to proceed to find the range of this function.

Answer (score 1):

The term $e^xln(x)5^{x^2+2}$ is positive for $x>1$.

At $x=4$, the function has a pole with sign change (the numerator is negative for
 $2<x<5$). So, for $2<x<4$ , the function is positive and because of
 $f(2)=0$ and $$\lim_{x->4-0}=+\infty$$ , every nonnegative value belongs
 to the range.

For $4<x<5$ , the function is negative and because of $f(5)=0$ and $$\lim_{x->4+0}=-
\infty$$, every nonpositive value belongs to the range.

So the range is the complete set of the reals.